# Isolate the year from a vector with dates

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, character

how can you isolate the year from a vector with dates? or in general: how can you isolate part of a word (here, the last four letters of a word)?

```
date <- c("05.06.2001","02.10.2003","06.12.2004","01.01.2001","01.04.2003")
company <- c(1,1,1,2,2)

mydf <- data.frame(date, company)
mydf

#         date company
# 1 05.06.2001       1
# 2 02.10.2003       1
# 3 06.12.2004       1
# 4 01.01.2001       2
# 5 01.04.2003       2
```

the output should look like this:

```
#         date company year
# 1 05.06.2001       1 2001
# 2 02.10.2003       1 2003
# 3 06.12.2004       1 2004
# 4 01.01.2001       2 2001
# 5 01.04.2003       2 2003
```

I've tried to use lubridate package

```
require(lubridate)
mydf$year <- year(mydf$date)
```

but, i want to be able to do it in general, not with a package that works only for dates.

Comment: -1: What have you tried?

Comment: Considering your update, perhaps you should also edit your title.

Comment: I personally still think this an easily google-able question.

Comment: @ Ananda Mahto & bartektartanus: thank you for helping!

Comment: @ Codoremifa: thank you for letting me know your humble opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches, one date based and one character based:

```
with(mydf, substr(date, nchar(as.character(date)) - 3, 
                  nchar(as.character(date))))
# [1] "2001" "2003" "2004" "2001" "2003"

format(as.Date(mydf$date, "%d.%m.%Y"), "%Y")
# [1] "2001" "2003" "2004" "2001" "2003"
```

`nchar` is overkill in this case since the strings are a fixed width, but this should give you an example of how to go from the end of the string backwards 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stri_sub` from [stringi](http://www.rexamine.com/resources/stringi/) package to get last 4 characters like this:

```
require(stringi)    
stri_sub(mydf$date, from=-4)
## [1] "2001" "2003" "2004" "2001" "2003"
```

negative value used in `from` parameter means that characters should be counted from the end of a string. Default value for `to` parameter is -1 which means 'till the end', so there is no need to change this.